# Magento SOAP WebService -> User Login

Tags: php, web-services, soap, magento

I'm writing a web service for communication between a mobile device and magento, i'm using SOAP webservices which Magento provides, however, i'm lost at User Authentication, i need to authenticate my system user (not api user). Is there any clue over this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you want to use a "admin" account to authenticate for web services? May offer some help: http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/629-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-1

Comment: No, thats what i've already done, i want to authenticate a 'user' account from that 'admin' account, hope you get the point.

Comment: It seems to be a tradition to not point this fundamental difference of apis in the respective manual.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SOAP Api for logging an user account in magento as it does not support that feature, you have to approach it in another way, maybe overriding controller file in Mage Customer named AccountController.php.

Try to add a new method which can communicate with server with JSON variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST api to authenticate customer.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

This approach seems to be more convenient, since you may receive a products list with applied catalog rules for logged in customer (let's say applied by customer group). SOAP API does not provide such feature (you can only receive products list as admin user).

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::app();
$user = "snjha77@gmail.com";
$pass = "admin123";
$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
    try
    {
        $session->login( $user, $pass);
        $customer = $session->getCustomer();
        //echo "valid";
        $userID = $session->getCustomer()->getId();
    $return_array['customer_id'] = $userID;
        $return_array['status'] = 1;
        $return_array['message'] = "Login is valid";
        echo json_encode($return_array);
        } catch( Exception $e ) {
            $return_array['status']= 0;
        $return_array['message']="Login is invalid";
        echo json_encode($return_array);
              }
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do that. If you have access to files through FTP then you can get_file_content of Database config file then connect to database from external source and perform user access check.

*Apply on your own risk. Might it not valid. But you can try that!*